How to use move semantics in a loop and avoid copying?
I created a little parser and would like to make the looped part as fast as possible. Thus I would like to avoid copying using move semantics instead. But I can't understand how to combine move semantics and loops.
My loop looks similar to this:
string word = "";
string s = "pip pip pop som"
unordered_map<string, int> dic;

for (char c : s) {
    if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') {  // lower case 
        word.push_back(c);
    }
    else if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') {  // upper case
        word.push_back(c + 32);
    }
    else if (!word.empty()) {  // word ended
        ++dic[word]; // I would like to avoid copying here
        word.clear();
    }
}
if (!word.empty()) {
    ++dic[word];
}

dic would contain:

"som" 1
"pip" 2
"pop" 1

I tried to std::move(word) into the dic, but it didn't work.
Can you, please advice on how to avoid copying here, and to use std::move?
I sadly can't create the word variable inside the loop.
When I made a minimal example for the question, it got even more confusing:
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <map>
#include <ranges>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    map<string, int> m;
    string word;

    for (auto i : views::iota(0, 10)) {
        word.push_back('a');
        ++m[word];  // I would like to avoid copying here
        word.clear();
    }

    for (auto [word, count] : m) {
        cout << word << ' ' << count << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

Depending on what you write in the first loop, the output will be different.
word.push_back('a');
++m[word];
word.clear();

outputs:

a 10

word.push_back('a');
++m[word];

outputs:

a 1
aa 1
aaa 1
aaaa 1
aaaaa 1
aaaaaa 1
aaaaaaa 1
aaaaaaaa 1
aaaaaaaaa 1
aaaaaaaaaa 1

word.push_back('a');
++m[move(word)];

outputs:

a 4
aa 3
aaa 2
aaaa 1

The last one is confusing me. Looks like it doesn't move the value, but it also doesn't copy it on every iteration.
I can imagine, why it doesn't move - because the variable word is being used on the next iterations, and it's lifetime is longer.
But why it copies so chaotically ?

if (c - 96u < 27u) {  // 'a' <= c <= 'z' this comment and condition look divergent. Invalid.

I recommend you learn about std::tolower. No need for those checks.

Read the manual, move works only if the key doesn't exist. In your case, move never works due to short string optimization.

I also recommend you use std::unordered_map, since key-order is not important.

OT: you do not gain much by moving the string, when in next iteration you need again a string to be populated. You pay. Either for the copy, or for one by one adding characters to an empty string.

And there should be only one copy, no matter how many equal words you have... Only time a copy is needed is when they key doesn't exist in the map. The rest of the time there's no need to copy the key again (for an ordered map there might be lot of comparisons, but no copying).

@Someprogrammerdude, thanks for the advice. Edited. I actually use unordered_map, and use map for the example.

Parsing is probably the least suitable project to learn multi-threading on. Getting a single token stream split across threads for parsing is an active research topic. The multi-threading part is trivial; parsing - not. Unless you want to be implementing research papers in your "learning to code" efforts, I'd advise not to. You will also have to learn to use a profiler (Intel's for example) from the get-go. Otherwise you will have no idea whether you're optimizing or pessimizing. Like with this "move not copy" thing... where pretty much all the time is spent in the memory allocator anyway.

As far as things a CPU can do, copying data is probably the fastest. The idea with avoiding copying is not so much that copies are expensive - they are not at all. It is the standard memory allocator that makes copies expensive, usually - especially for small objects. With a suitable memory allocator like a per-thread pool allocator, and a well thought-through inter-thread data passing, copying small things is no big deal if they are in the cache. Making parsers fast is usually about vectorizing on one thread, not multi-threading.

Take a look e.g. at the fastest JSON parsers out there. The outperform everything else on a single core, because single cores can do a lot of parallel work if you set up the problem right. Instead of a parser, you might consider things like simple image processing. That does scale across threads very nicely, until you run out of memory bandwidth that is.

The first line of your question is the most prominent. It's the first thing people read, and it is shown in the list of questions (under the title). It is your opportunity to sell your question, and you squandered it. Instead of move semantics, you start your question by mentioning threading, which is not only orthogonal to your question, but also is not mentioned later. Bad idea. Good questions usually don't need the story of how you came across them. And in the cases where context might be significant, the context should be towards the end of the question.

I had some luck searching for [c++] insert map without copy, but I guess what I found falls short of being a duplicate since there was no mention of using the return value of emplace/try_emplace, which would be useful for "as fast as possible". Still, there may be value in reading inserting object in a map without copying the object and Inserting heavy objects into std::map.

TL;DR: You cannot gain performance by moving instead of copying the string when you still need its value in the next iteration.

Nothing really weird going on.
First case:

word.push_back('a');
++m[word];
word.clear();


Each iteration you add an 'a' to the string, you increment the count for the string "a", you clear the string to start next iteration with an empty word. You do that 10 times. Hence after the loop the count for "a" is 10.
Next case:

word.push_back('a');
++m[word];


Each iteration you add one more 'a' to word and increment the count of the current word. You do that 10 times. After the loop you have incremented the count of 10 different words, each one character longer than the previous one.
Last case:

word.push_back('a');
++m[move(word)];


The move constructor of std::string leaves the moved from string in a valid but unspecified state (read more here). The contents of word could in principle be anything after you moved from it.
What you see is effect of short string optimization. Short strings are stored directly in the std::string. No dynamic allocations are made. Hence there is nothing to be moved. Moving the short string is effectively copying it. Only after the string is so long it cannot use short string optimization the moved from string is empty after the move. None of this can be counted on. As mentioned above, the moved from string is in unspecified state. You are not supposed to move from it when you still need the value and when you need the moved from string empty you have to call clear.


I understand, why it doesn't move - because the variable word is being used on the next iterations, and it's lifetime is longer.

Your understanding is wrong in this point. ++m[move(word)]; does move the string in every iteration. That you use the string in the next iteration is not relevant. By calling std::move(word) you pretend that word will not be used anymore. If you use it nevertheless you are on your own.

As mentioned in a comment, ++m[std::move(word)]; only does the move when word is not found in the map. And same goes for the copy. ++m[word]; only copies word when it is not in the map. When it is in the map then [] looks up the element and ++ increments it. For example in your first case only a single copy is made.

I got it, in my case, strings of length 1-3 were optimized, and of length 4 not, and was fully moved. Though, in that case it would be 4 4 2 2, still confusing, but that's what UB should be  :)

@MaxCury there is no undefined behavior. Its only unspecified. The difference is important.Unspecified only means that it depends on the implementation. Undefined means it could in principle depend on the phase of the moon and the temparature of your aquarium. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior


The last one is confusing me. It doesn't move the value, but it also doesn't copy it on every iteration.

That's because the map constructs a key only when the key is not in the map already.
Which constructor is used depends on the type passed into operator[]. When it's an rvalue reference, move construction of the key will be done, otherwise the key will be copy-constructed.
So, the word has to be cleared after every use, even when potentially move-constructing a new key in the map. When the key already exists, the  word will not be used for move-construction, and will remain unaltered.
For reference, the map stores elements that are (string, int) pairs: std::pair<std::string, int>.

Without a benchmark it is hard to say that avoiding copying changes anything at all. But let's indulge anyway:
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
    std::string word = "";
    std::string s = "pip pop pip som som som";
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> dic;

    for (char c : s) {
        if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') {  // lower case
            word.push_back(c);
        } else if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') {  // upper case
            word.push_back(c + 32);
        } else if (!word.empty()) {  // word ended
            ++dic[std::move(word)];
            word.clear();
        }
    }
    if (!word.empty()) {  // word ended
        ++dic[std::move(word)];
    }

    for (const auto& pair : dic) {
        printf("%s %d\n", pair.first.c_str(), pair.second);
    }
}

Noteworthy:

std::move does not actually move anything. It is a cast that allows move construction to happen if needed. Whether the word was moved into the dictionary key or not depends on whether try_emplace succeeded or failed. It fails when the key already exists. try_emplace is used internally by the operator[] overload that accepts an rvalue reference.

It helps to have complete, working code in the question that someone answering the question can paste into an IDE or source file. That means you need working code without parts irrelevant to the question, and just paste it into the question.


Ideally, short C or C++ examples should be working on godbolt - that is usually the fastest way for anyone to tackle them when answering a question.
I developed this answer on godbolt, and here's the output:
som 3
pop 1
pip 2

For benchmarking, you should get familiar with quick-bench.com. Transferring code from godbolt to quick-bench is a single click operation.

++dic[std::move(word)] is equivalent to:
const auto itbool = dic.try_emplace(std::move(word), int{});
++ itbool.first->second;

itbool is a std::pair<iterator, bool>. The iterator iterates over std::pair<key, value>. Thus, to get to the integer, we first get the iterator-to-a-pair through itbool.first, then increment the value (second) element part of the key-value pair.

I must notice that T&& doesn't always mean rvalue reference (I made such a mistake on an interview, haha, and now I share my discovery)
https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers

P.S. I measured it on the 514MB Bible, and yes it's faster by 10% - 55 sec without my optimizations, and 50 sec with them, on average.

@MaxCury concrete_type && always means rvalue reference. type_parameter && means a universal reference. So you're right, of course, but it's not relevant here. I used the term correctly.

@MaxCury There's nothing I can say about that without seeing the rest of the code, especially that you mention optimizations in plural. I can almost assure you that there are much bigger "fish to fry" in the optimization game in your code. Using a faster string class that uses a pool allocator would be probably a big win, since I imagine you must be allocating a lot of strings.
